# How Microsoft protects for example Sql Server binaries from reverse engineering?

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++, sql-server-2008-r2, reverse-engineering

I am interested in how Microsoft protects Sql Server binaries from reverse engineering ? 
For example I also have some C++ dll and I want to protect it from reverse engineering. Is this logical thing to do is dll is compiled to machine code ?

Comment: It is not possible, even in theory, to "protect [binaries] from reverse engineering".  The program has to *run*, after all, and it's not possible to run the program without revealing the sequence of machine instructions that it executes.  A sufficiently determined reverse engineer *will* find a way to do their job.  Microsoft knows this, so they do not bother obfuscating their binaries.  In fact, they [reveal debugging information about many of them](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503) to make life easier for application programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no technical defense against reverse engineering. It is always possible to run code in an in-circuit emulator in order to fully observe and understand its function. This is extremely time consuming work, but it can be done if the payoff is worth it. One famous example from the 1990's was [Andrew Schulman's work](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201608340) that uncovered hidden features of the Windows 95 API.

While there are no technical barriers to this kind of analysis, there are certainly legal and practical limits to the usefulness of the process. Given enough time with qualified engineers, you could completely reverse engineer any large software package, including Microsoft Windows, Office, or the Oracle database binaries. Your reward for this effort would be the ability to produce unlicensed, illegal copies of the software. This would have no commercial or practical value.

Obfuscation utilities that are used for .NET or Java applications address a specific problem with these languages: since they support inspection of method and property names, it is possible to reverse engineer not just the function of the code but the public identifiers used in the original source code. Although C++ uses symbolic names for linking, it does not have the same rich naming information available, so obfuscation is not necessary. It should be noted that even if code is reverse engineered with public identifiers, the same practical and legal limitations apply to the process.

Comment: SQL Server symbols are publicly available on the MS Symbol Server (at least for some builds) and quite a lot can be gleaned from this. [example](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/08/09/sql-server-seeks-and-binary-search.aspx)

Comment: @Paul so you think only possible solution is to have patent on that code ?

Comment: @RadenkoZec The correct solution is to accept that (a) if someone wants to steal your ideas, they will no matter what you do, and (b) it is overwhelmingly likely that no one will ever bother.  Let go of the desire to hoard your ideas, and be happy.

Comment: On a practical note - why bother? Spend all that effort to reverse engineer a product. Cannot advertise the fact and you run the gauntlet of the law. Then they come out with another version. Throw all that work in the bin and start over?!

Comment: @Zack - You can go down the business model of given the software out for free and charge for the bells and whistles (i.e. extra functionality, somebody at the end of a 'phone, etc).

Comment: @EdHeal Problem that I have is that I do have something that I need to patent but I don't have large sums of many to claim international patents. So I just want to go with v1 and after patent it.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm not in the game of trying to make money in the first place.  I understand that that can work very well or very badly, depending on the market.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscating your assemblies will offer reasonable protection to your DLL. There are many obsfucating softwares present around. You may learn more about them and decide which one would be best for you.

Comment: Hi Luftwaffe. Thanks for answer.I want to know is Microsoft obfuscating your Sql Server assemblies ? If I do so it will affect my performance... Also I don't know is it reasonable to do so because code is compiled to machine code ?

Comment: @RadenkoZec - Obfusation means just to make it difficult to read and understand. That does not effect performance of the computer. As to effecting your performance - that is a different question!

Comment: Hi Ed. I do have some really mission critical C++ code. If I only change order of declared variables I got 5% change in performance so I think that obfuscation will indeed effect my performance..

Comment: @RadenkoZec - Guess you do not understand obfuscation. As to this 5% figure I be interest for you to give an example that the order of variables in a program (your choice of language) makes that difference.

Comment: @EdHeal Maybe not Ed. I do know there is few ways to do obfuscation. One is just change names of variables,classes and methods and another is to give nested calls to functions(this will affect my performance)

Comment: @RadenkoZec - So where does this 5% figure come from? It may even imrpove performance!

Answer (score 0):

A dll is machine code. anything can be reversed engineered. They rely on two things. The effort involved and obfuscation.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention that with MS$ you get things like upgrades, compatibility (why do you think they change the format of Word documents etc. once in a while)

Comment: Hi Ed. Thanks for fast answer. I want to know how Microsoft protecting his critical code. For example Sql server internally uses structure that is some implementation of B+ tree. How they for example protect your own implementation of B+ tree from reverse engineering ?